# A function which is not continuous on the normal topology on R, but is continuous under the 0-pointed topology

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the $0$-pointed topology on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. a set is open iff it is open in the normal topology and contains $0.$ Is there a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuous in this topology but not continuous under the normal topology ?

Comment: I posted an answer but I guess too quickly - I have to rethink it...

Answer (score 2):

Let $X=\{a,b\}$ with the topology that a set $U\subseteq X$ is open if and only if it contains $a$. Consider $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $a\mapsto 0$ and $b\mapsto 1$. Then, for any $s<t$ we have that $f^{-1}((s,t))$ is open in $X$ if and only if it contains $a$, i.e., if and only if $0\in (s,t)$. Hence, $f$ is not continuous as a map into $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology.

However, it *is* continuous into the zero pointed topology, since any open set *does* contain $0$, and hence, it's pre-image is open by definition.

Or were you asking about a map from $\mathbb{R}$ into itself?

Comment: Ah, I should have specified -- I did mean from R to R

Comment: Hm... giving it some thought, I don't quite have a finished proof but note that such a map must be ordinarily continuous at $0$. This makes me think that any map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which is continuous in this topology should also be continuous in the usual topology.

Comment: i mean your proof still basically works: send everything except 1 to 0, and send 1 to 1

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess you're right, because the $0$-sequence converges to everything.

Comment: Is it this simple? Wow, I had to be temporarily blind - hopefully just temporarily...

Comment: Well, I mean... weird topologies are weird.